# What's a general method to solve this calculation puzzle?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

[image: Calculation puzzle image]

I need help to work out how to solve this puzzle. The puzzle is very self-explanatory...

Comment: What is the source of this puzzle?

Comment: no idea, a fellow mate asked me to solve it

Comment: 4 variables and 4 equations, wolframalpha gives a solution $9/10, 21/10,59/10,10$

Answer (score 2):

This is a system of 4 equations with 4 variables:

> $a+b=8$
>  $a*c=21$
>  $b-d=5$
>  $c*d=9$

From 2nd and 4th equation:

> $a=21/c$
>  $d=9/c$

For easier writing let's put $1/c=x$ and insert $a$ and $d$ into 1st and 3rd equation:

> $21x+b=8$
>  $b-9x=5$
>  so $30x = 3$ or $x=1/10$

From here it is easy:

> $c=10$, $a=21/10$, $d=9/10$ and $b=59/10$